# PhantomJS page.evaluateAsync is ignored with ajax call inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

I am trying to make an ajax call with phantomjs.

The only resource i found regarding this is: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate-async.html

Although when i try to make an ajax call though evaluateasync, the code within is not being executed.  Even console.log('Async'); not being printed.

Any ideas?

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open("", function(status) {
    page.includeJs("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", function() {
        console.log('includejs');

        page.evaluateAsync(function() {
            console.log('Async');


            $.ajax({
                url : "some url",
                type : 'post',
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('success');

                },
                error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log(jqXHR+'-'+exception);
                    console.log('error');

                }
            });

        });
});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.evaluateAsync` is not ignored, it's just that `console.log` inside of `page.evaluate/evaluateAsync()` function is not the same as in the PhantomJS script, it's running in the sandboxed environment and uou have to subscribe to it:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Also, if you try to log an object, as in

```
console.log(jqXHR+'-'+exception);
```

you'll get [object Object] result, instead try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+'-'+exception);
```

**Even more important**: if after opening one site you're gonna do ajax requests to another, run your script with --web-security=false switch to allow cross-domain XHR.

```
phantomjs --web-security=false evalasync.js
```

Comment: it works except for " --web-security=false switch to allow cross-domain XHR". I am not able to call cross domain. Getting "{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}-error" as an error

Comment: So, you use the switch and the error persists? Are you sure the remote page works well?

Comment: i am able to access the domain without an issue, and i can run the code directly from the outside server it self. but it just does not work when i try to run the code from another server. I will mark the question as answered since you were able to answer my other question.

Comment: Thanks, but still that it won't work is strange. Can you disclose some real code to debug?